# Using GREP with Merge in InDesign

Tags: grep

I'm doing a data merge for a letter. In the data file there is a column for "title" (Mr., Mrs., Dr. etc.) So I set up my InDesign document with:`<<title>> <<first>> <<middle>> <<last>>` with spaces in between each. However, some of the names in the mailing list do not have a "title" so when the merge is completed, it leaves the space that would be between "title" and "first" like this:

```
 John Doe
1234 Anystreet
Anytown, USA
```

I need to remove the space at the beginning of the name line so it will line up with the address. I felt like this would be a good use of GREP, but I don't have a lot of experience with writing expressions. It doesn't seem like it would be that difficult. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Set *Find What* to `^`  (a ^ followed by a space), leave *Change to* empty and press *Change All*.

[image]

`^` starts a selection at *Beginning of Paragraph* and a space simply selects a space. This way you select all places where there is a beginning of a paragraph followed by a space.

If there can be multiple spaces you can keep running the search until there are no more matches or add a `+` after the space like this:

`^ +`

The `+` means *One or More Times*. So this will select all places where there is a beginning of a paragraph followed by one or more spaces.

(If you can't remember these symbols you can insert them by pressing the *@* button to the right of the *Find what* field.)

Comment: Thanks Wolff. I'll give that a try.